# Timestamp indexing

Tags: mysql, indexing, innodb

If I have a table with columns: `item_id, user_id, vote, date` what columns should I put the index on considering:

1. I'll need to fetch votes by date for time ranges and
2. there cannot be more than one vote for each item by a user.

Should the index be sorted ASC or DESC if I want to fetch dates that are more recent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PRIMARY:item_id,user_id

INDEX: date

Sort DESC for latest first

Note: I assume you are storing date as UNIX TIMESTAMP  (From your question title Timestamp Indexing)

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
CREATE INDEX mytime_index ON myTable (user_id, date);
```

You can't set `asc` and `desc` at index level as it's bydefault on `asc`.

Check this out--------------
Quoted from [mysql website create indices](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-index.html)

An index_col_name specification can end with ASC or DESC. These keywords are permitted for future extensions for specifying ascending or descending index value storage. Currently, they are parsed but ignored; index values are always stored in ascending order

Comment: That doesn't accomplish any of the objectives.

Comment: @Jack can you please clarify what you meant? :)

Comment: I'm fairly sure the index you suggested won't prevent users voting more than once on an item

Comment: How does a spanning index over `user_id, date` help in finding votes by date unless you already know the user? And an index doesn't prevent duplicates.